# Scrollable flexed content inside scrollable flexed content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried to make this question as generic as possible. Essentially, I have a vertical (column) flex layout inside another vertical flex layout. In the outer layout, I'd like the main area (`outer-main`, in my example) to fill remaining vertical real estate. In the inner layout, I'd also like the main area (`inner-main`) to fill remaining vertical real estate.

This is working properly on the outer layout, but in the inner layout, I'd like just the main area (`inner-main`) to be scrollable, not the entire layout. So `inner-header` should always be visible, with just `inner-main` filling remaining space and being scrollable.

How can I tweak my CSS to achieve this?

**The snippet is easier to see when run in full-screen**

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 60vh;
  padding: 5px;
}

.outer > div {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.outer .outer-header {
  height: 10vh;
}

.outer .outer-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.outer .outer-main > div + div,
.outer > div + div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.outer .outer-main > div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.outer .outer-main .inner-main {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer-header">Outer Header</div>
  <div class="outer-main">
    Outer Main
    <div class="inner-header">Inner Header</div>
    <div class="inner-main">
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you define for `.inner-main` for example `height: 45vh;` and then from there parent will wrap all child elements?

Comment: Because I don't always want it to take up 45% of viewport height. I only added in the `vh` units to this example so they'd take up space to produce the issue. In actuality, that content is highly dynamic, so I don't want to be locked into any set heights in the final product. That's why I'm using flex layout. I'd like the outer layout to be as short as it needs to be, without growing past a certain height. Then the inner layout should simply cue off that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I simply needed to add `overflow: auto` to the `inner-main` div, and that allows it to scroll. See updated snippet below.

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 60vh;
  padding: 5px;
}

.outer > div {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.outer .outer-header {
  height: 10vh;
}

.outer .outer-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.outer .outer-main > div + div,
.outer > div + div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.outer .outer-main > div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.outer .outer-main .inner-main {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer-header">Outer Header</div>
  <div class="outer-main">
    Outer Main
    <div class="inner-header">Inner Header</div>
    <div class="inner-main">
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
      <div>Inner Main Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```